# How can i get input value, which located outside React app?

Tags: reactjs

I have `<select>`
outside React app

example
index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

const el = document.getElementById('root');

ReactDOM.render(<App param={el.getAttribute('someParams')}, el);
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
    <select id="select" name="select">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    <div id="root" someParams="123"></div>
  ...
```

In App.jsx I want get `<select>` value when `<select>` changes. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside App or any child component you can access the  element the old javascript way and add a listener:

```
let select = document.getElementById('select');

select.onchange = (e) => {
    console.log('Do something');
}
```

Comment: Strange, I did something like that, but I had a mistake. Your solution works! Thank you!

Comment: @Green176 it may depend on which part of App.jsx you apply this code, for example, in the constructor I'm not sure is gonna work.